# What is the value of $a+2b$ if $\frac{OP}{EF}=\frac{a}{}b$ in $ABCD$ rectangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

> **BD** is diagonal in **ABCD** rectangle and **E**, **F** is the mid point of **BC**, **CD** respectively. Line **BD** intersects **AE**,
>   **AF** at **O**, **P** respectively. If $\dfrac{OP}{EF} = \dfrac{a}b$, then **a+2b**=?

[image]

Comment: Actually I tried and found that EF was half of BD. But I was not able to understand how am I supposed to relate this information with OP.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I'll assume that $a$ and $b$ are the width and height of the rectangle.

Extend $AD$, $EF$ and $AB$ until they meet in points $G,H$. You can easily prove that triangles $BEG$, $CEF$ and $DHF$ are congruent. It follows that $GE=EF=FH$. Lines $EF$ and $BD$ are parallel so by Thales $BO=OP=PD$ too. If the length of diagonal BD is $d$ it means that $OP=d/3$.

On the other side, $EF=d/2$ and from the text of the prboelm we know that:

$$\frac{OP}{EF}=\frac{d \over 3}{d \over 2}=\frac23=\frac ab \implies 3a=2b$$

It follows that $a+2b=4a$.

Comment: I did not understand how $BO = OP = PD$. Could you please explain it how you proved that?

Comment: Take a look at triangles $BEG$ and $ECF$ for example. They are congruent by ASA ($BE=EC$, $\angle BEG=\angle CEF$, $\angle GBE=\angle ECF$. Therefore $GE=EF$ and in the same way $EF=FH$. By Thales, $GE/BO=EF/OP=FH/PD$. If all numerators are equal, denominators are equal too.